# Django F() division - How to avoid rounding off

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this code:

```
q = MyModel.objects.order_by('-value1').annotate(
            res=ExpressionWrapper(
                (F('value1') / F('value2')), 
                output_field=FloatField()),
            )

for i in q:                                          
    print(i.value1, i.value2, i.res)
```

So, the output will be:

```
5 10 0.0
1 2 0.0
```

But I need

```
5 10 0.5
1 2 0.5
```

Wy **F()** rounded the result? How not to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `float(F('value1'))` ?

Comment: The thing about `F` expressions is that Python doesn't know about the values, but hands the operation (division in this case) to the database. For PostgreSQL and MySQL, integer division results in an integer, just like in Python 2.x

Comment: @trantu float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'F'

Comment: @schwobaseggl in sqlite the same. I find https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet and there is example named "Cost per page"

Comment: @tim In that example, however, `price` is a `DecimalField`, not an `IntegerField`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result you are expecting is really easy to achieve with a raw query and really, I mean really hard to achieve with pure django.

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, ExpressionWrapper, F

template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS FLOAT)'
fv1 =  Func(F('value1'), function='CAST', template=template)
fv2 =  Func(F('value2'), function='CAST', template=template)
ew = ExpressionWrapper(fv1/fv2, output_field = FloatField())


q = MyModel.objects.order_by('-value1').annotate(res = ew)
```

You wouldn't accuse this of being elegant but it works on both Mysql and Postgresql.

To provide some background. The rounding is done by the database doing *integer division* because the field you have are ints. If you want decimal division you need to cast them to decimals. Unfortunately casting is not very easy with Django.

Postgresql has a really elegant way to cast to float. value1::float but this cannot be made use of from inside django (at least as far as I know)

Answer (score 31):

Simply make use of `F()`'s support for multiplication to convert one factor to decimal number.

Combined expression then would look like:

```
from decimal import Decimal

q = MyModel.objects.order_by('-value1').annotate(
            res=ExpressionWrapper(
                (F('value1') * Decimal('1.0') / F('value2')), 
                output_field=FloatField()),
            )
```

I find this more elegant way then write raw SQL CAST on value1 field and then do the division.

Comment: not trying to find fault (I've given you an upvote) but this produced TypeError: unbound method select_format() must be called with FloatField instance as first argument (got SQLCompiler instance instead) for me

Comment: @e4c5 Can you give some more specific info (django ver, db backed etc.) ? I've tested it with Django 1.8 and Postgres and it works as described. Produces correct SQL: `django.db.connection[-1]['sql'] == SELECT … (("shop_product"."value1" * 1.0) / "shop_product"."value2") AS "res" FROM … ` . `res` contains correct decimal result like 0.6666666666666666 when value1 == 2 and value2 == 3.

Comment: django 1.9 postgresql 9.5 sorry I cannot reproduce the error now as I didn't save the db

Comment: @e4c5 NP, just curious why it failed in your case. Implicit conversion by multiplying with `1.0` worked all the time for me, even at cases where CAST didn't.

Comment: yeah, I realized it might be a local issue and recognized your answer to be a good one.

Comment: Why do you use `Decimal('1.0')` instead of just `1.0`?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately the ORM `F('value1') / F('value2')` operation is executed on the database side, therefore if both fields declared as `integer` you will definitely get the `integer` result. In Django **1.11.7** you could simply cast one of the `F()` expression to `decimal` like this:

```
 qs = (
     MyModel.objects
     .annotate(
         res=ExpressionWrapper(
             F('value1') * 1.0 / F('value2'), 
             output_field=FloatField(),
         ),
     )
 )
```

Answer (score 5):

In v1.10, Django introduced a [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function which makes this (almost) a breeze – the qualification being that you either need two casts or need to wrap the whole thing in an [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) to avoid a `FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.`

```
q = MyModel.objects.annotate(
            res=ExpressionWrapper(
                (Cast('value1', FloatField()) / F('value2')), 
                output_field=FloatField()),
            )
```

This is functionally equivalent to multiplying the enumerator by `1.0`, but an explicit cast makes your intention clearer than a multiplication by a number.