# Does Cast Function perform rounding before casting Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, casting

I expect the [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function of Django, to do only casting e.g `7.6` will be `7` without performing any rounding.

For example in Mysql the following:

```
select CAST(((<value> - 1) div 30) AS SIGNED INTEGER)
```

With a `value` equal to `227` will produce `7`.

But with Django's `Cast`, the following:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(time_window = Cast((F('field') - 1) / 30, IntegerField()))
```

will produce `8` for some record having the value `227` for `field`.

Are my expectations are wrong, or there is some flag to prevent this rounding behavior?

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091812/django-f-division-how-to-avoid-rounding-off

Comment: `div` will perform integer division. `226 div 30` gives you 7 (remainder 16). On the other hand `226 / 30` gives you 7.5333 and `CAST` will round it to 8.

Answer (score 0):

As @Salman_A commented, the *sql* query is doing **integer division**, while the django query is using `CAST` which will do the **rounding**.

The problem is you can not simply replace `/` with `//` in the django query because this will raise a `TypeError`.

The solution was to do the *devision* followed by a *floor* operation, somthing like:

```
Floor(F('Field') / <some constant>, output_field=IntegerField()),
```